# C - Threads with the same socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I'm having some trouble with sockets and threads. I have on the main thread a implementation of poll that listens for all new connections. When a client connects to my server, I save this socket on a struct along with some more stuff that I need, and then deposit this struct in a list that is shared with another thread. This thread will begin whenever I start the program. 
The problem is that when I'm trying send something on the second thread by the socket that i saved before, errno says "Bad File Descriptor"

Any idea ?

Thanks!!

**mainThread**

```
void main() {
  pthread_t secondThread;

  ...

  while(1) {
     poll(programs, BACKLOG,TIMEOUT);

     if (programs[0].revents == POLLIN)
     {
        index = accept_connection(&programs[1], &programs[0].fd,BACKLOG,1); 
        char* file = receive_program(programs[1].fd,bufsize);

        if (strlen(file) >0) {
           t_newProgram* program = new_program(file,programs[index].fd);

           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           list_add(list_of_programs,program);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        programs[0].revents = 0;
     } else {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < (BACKLOG + 1); i++) {
           if (programs[i].revents == POLLIN) {
              accept_connection(&programs[i], &programs[0].fd,BACKLOG,i);
              char* file = receive_program(programs[i].fd,bufsize);

              if(strlen(file) >0) {
                 t_newProgram* program = new_program(file,programs[i].fd);

                 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                 list_add(list_of_programs,program);                                
                 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
              }
              programs[i].revents = 0;
           }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

**secondThread**

```
...

void program_reject() {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   t_newProgram* prog = (t_newProgram*)list_get(list_of_programs,0);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   int errno = 0;
   socklen_t len = sizeof(errno2);

   int retval = getsockopt(*(prog)->socketProg,SOL_SOCKET,SO_ERROR,&errno2,&len);
   int size = strlen("Program rejected")+1;

   setsockopt(*pu, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF,&size, strlen("Program rejected")+1);
   int sendVar = send(*pu,"Program rejected",strlen("Program rejected")+1,0);

   if(sendVar == -1) {
      puts(strerror(errno));
   }

   free(prog);
}
```

...

Comment: Code example. Need code example.

Comment: I added the code. The synchronization mechanisms that I used is mutex
Thanks!

Comment: the error is not clear at first site (at least for me :)). I would start debugging by checking the value of the fd variable you add to the program struct, in both threads. Most probably it gets corrupted somewhere. A debugger might help setting a watch point to got a breakpoint when the code change that specific memory location.

Comment: I debbug the program and the variable is the same in both threads.I does not understand that send() returns -1.

Comment: I'm baffled. I was expecting the fd in the second thread to have been mangled somewhere :-/ BTW: I'm I missing something or the var **pu** passed to setsockopt() and send() is not defined in the posted code?

Comment: I don't think secondThread's call to setsockopt(SO_SNDBUF) makes any sense; you aren't intended to set the kernel's outgoing-socket-data-buffer to the size of the data you are about to send, and most kernels that I'm aware of wouldn't honor a buffer-size that small anyway.

Comment: Thanks for yours reply.I solved it by changing, on the t_newProgram, the int * socketProg field by int socketProg.